# Refresh wheel freezes until onRefresh() is finished

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

When I swipe up to refresh my ListView, I perform a click using performClick(), but the wheel freezes until everything that's under the onClickListener is executed.

```
btini.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Code here
            refreshlistmain.setRefreshing(false);

refreshlistmain.setOnRefreshListener(
                    new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            btini.performClick();
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Since the code under onClick() is quite long, the wheel stays frozen for a couple of seconds before disappearing.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score -1):

This code arrangement is wrong. It a recursive call. On each click a new `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` will be registered. Just use it like below . Perform long running task and then at last call `refreshlistmain.setRefreshing(false);`. If long running task is on worker thread then you need to wait for it to complete.

```
btini.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         // Do stuff
            refreshlistmain.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
    refreshlistmain.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    btini.performClick();
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I still have the problem

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have some long task on UI thread. It will not freeze not only `SwipeToRefreshLayout` but also any animation or `ProgressBar` you have (got that).

**Solution**

Put your task (which you are doing after button click) in [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) or different thread. Which will run Asynchronously.